# How to correctly (good practice) generate gpg keys in batch mode (unattended) WITH a passphrase

Tags: pgp, key-generation

I'm writing a web interface in PHP to generate keys. I'm familiar with gpg's command line options, particularly --batch. I'm also familiar with PHP's GnuPG API.

I can't find a way to safely pass the user's password from the web interface to the gpg command line because gpg uses a pinentry program? PHP's GnuPG functions don't include an API to generate keys.

What other way is there to generate keys, unattended, other than creating a batch file with the passphrase in that file like so:

```
Key-Type: default
Subkey-Type: default
Name-Real: Bob
Name-Email: bob@gmail.com
Expire-Date: 2021-12-25
Passphrase: mysecretpassphrase
%commit
```

Note: putting the passphrase on the command line with --passphrase is not wise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer by reading the whole manual.

`$ man gpg` says around line 1944:

--passphrase-fd n

Read  the passphrase from file descriptor n.

and

--passphrase-file file

Read the passphrase from the file.